# How to import reference to text files inside a folder in java?

Tags: java, file-io

I'm using JCreator. In learning Java. I had no problem reading and writing files until I decided to put all text files inside a folder.

```
-JavaSampleProject
    - src
       -sampletext.txt
       -sampletext1.txt
```

- This works when I call `Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("sampletext.txt");`

But when I made it like this:

```
-JavaSampleProject
    -src
        -FlatFile
            -sampletext.txt
            -sampletext1.txt
```

- This no longer works: `Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("sampletext.txt");`

I've tried adding "FlatFile\sample.txt" no errors,  but it did not work. Then I tried importing FlatFile.  It returned an error FlatFile package does not exist.

How would I avoid putting absolute path ("C:\...\..\FlatFile\sampletext.txt") to refer to my text files inside the FlatFile folder?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("filename/sampletext.txt"));
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `"FlatFile/sampletext.txt"`, and it would be useful to mention that `"FlatFile\\sampletext.txt"` will also work since the post mentioned using a single backslash.